# Assembly.LoadFrom returns same Assembly when assembly path and version differs

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

Imagine this scenario:

```
var ass1 = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Work\3.59\assembly1.dll");
var ass2 = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Work\3.60\assembly1.dll");

Debug.Assert(ass1 != ass2);
```

The above assert fails. It seems the second call returns the first assembly even if the two assemblies above have different versions and locations.

The assemblies are not stong-named and can't be signed.

Is there a way to force the framework to load them in the same context and domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Assembly.LoadFile(path)` instead.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx%3a)

> The LoadFrom method has the following disadvantages. Consider using
>   Load instead.
>
> If an assembly with the same identity is already loaded, LoadFrom
>   returns the loaded assembly even if a different path was specified.

From [CLR developer Suzanne Cook's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/07/21/assembly-identity.aspx):

> If the assembly is not strongly-named, then the version is ignored for
>   binding. But, if it is strongly-named, the entire version in the
>   assembly reference needs to match the found assembly.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can use Assembly.LoadFile(). 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx

Comment: hmm when i used LoadFile i get two assemblies instead of one i ApplicationDomain, why then? ( when loading 'same' assembly from different locations )

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to solve this problem today —— just signature for the assembly before you build the class library project. Because the Assembly.LoadFrom(string assemblyPath) method will load the assembly every time no matter whether those assemblies names are the same or not only if those assemblies are strong naming assembly.